# Editing templates in realtime using a JS library?

Tags: javascript, templates, user-interface

I'm trying to a create a dynamic templating interface for users to build their email templates however they see fit.

I want to allow them to insert any available dynamic data into the template during creation and show it in a preview in realtime as they make the changes.

Can I make this streamlined and elegant with something like AngularJS, Durandal, Ember or some other JS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to AngularJS or Ember, but I can say that, with Durandal, it doesn't really have to do with Durandal itself.  As developers, we employ various templating technologies--handlebars, knockout templates, Durandal's composition engine, etc.

But if you wish to expose this capability to users, it's a little different.  What may be trivial to us as developers could be confusing to end users.  So, first, consider the following:

- Presentation of the merger fields: {{PROJECT_NAME}}, or [[PROJECT_NAME]], or @ProjectName, etc.
- The means by which you wish to expose the available merger fields: every client-side entity will need a consistent way to expose the merger fields
- The means by which users will actually drop the merger fields into the email text: dropdown list where the user clicks on the merger field, autocomplete at the location of the caret, drag-and-drop from a sidebar list of merger fields, etc.
- A mini DSL--*domain specific language*--where the user has a few functions available for manipulation of the merger field: @uppercase({{PROJECT_NAME}}), @today(), etc.
- Security: encoding of the email text to thwart malice

We are currently developing the Durandal-based version of our desktop application.  Below are two screenshots of the *desktop* version and how we did what it is you're trying to do:

[image: email templates]
[image: selection of fields]

The Durandal version of the app looks a little bit different, but it's basically the same.

All of this is very doable in Durandal since Durandal depends on technologies you already know (or may know): JavaScript, Knockout, HTML5, and CSS.

When the user presses '[', the merger field selector pops up; when the user presses '@', the available functions pop up (right now, they're just @Uppercase, @OptionalNA, and @Optional).

**EXPOSING ENTITY PROPERTIES**

We took the approach of maintaining for each entity a dictionary that maps the string-based description of the merger field presented to the user, to the entity's observable:

```
this.mergerDict = {mergerField: "CONTACT_FIRST_NAME", firstName: this.firstName()}
```

where `this` is in the context of the entity.  A little bit of underscore.js magic makes this trivial.

But there are many ways of doing this, and no doubt we'll refactor as we move towards pushing the merger dictionary out to the end user via a more open-ended UI.

Comment: This is very good. Thanks for sharing. Now I know it is feasible. App will be web based though. So I can get a feel for development time, how many hours did it take to implement this? (if you don't mind me asking)

Comment: About 40 man-hours for the web version, 100 for the desktop version.